# У h1 появляется margin после подключения normalize, но я сбрасывала отступы с помощью *

Tags: css

В css пишу

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Подключаю normalize.css и из него у h1 появляется margin: 0.67em 0px;
А по макету мне нужен только margin-top: 53px

Прочитала, что у h1 приоритет перед *

Сработало, как ниже на примере, но так вроде никто не делает

```
*, h1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**В итоге, как обнулять margin у h1?**

Comment: у normalize нет задачи сбросить все свойства по умолчанию и сделать вашу страницу некрасивой. его задача исправить ошибки некоторых браузеров и сделать отображение одинаковым везде. также не рекомендуется указывать css свойства тегов и тем более *. нормальная практика писать стили для классов. подробнее обсуждение [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565762/use-margin0-padding0-if-i-link-normalize-css)

Answer (score 0):

Мне в университете предлагали такой способ для обнуления всех свойств сразу

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Взято с сайта [CSS reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
Но Вам же не нужны почти все эти свойства
Исходя из этого
Я думаю что Ваш вариант является допустимым